# How to import projection in readShapePoly() function? - R

Tags: r, shapefile, map-projections, r-maptools

I am importing a polygon shapefile from Arcmap that has already a projection set and comes with all its files (sbn,sbx,prj,etc).

However after I use the `readShapePoly` function, when I do a summary it looks like the projection information is blank. Is the projection included already or not recognized?

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min     max
x   35551.4 1585917
y 6318047.3 9408727
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]
Data attributes:
```

I know there is a `proj4string` attribute but it's not clear how to use it and the prj file it's already attached to the .shp file. I can consider another function that does a better job if there is one. Not sure if `rgdal` with `readOGR` does what I want.

edit follow up: I tried with `readOGR` thanks for the reply. I am using this code test<-readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer="grid") and the shapefile is here speedy.sh/Ry8rU/grid.zip and it still doesn't read the projection.

Comment: Yes. Use `readOGR()`, as it'll preserve/capture the projection info.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I just tried readOGR but it's not loading the projection. In the help page it states "PROJ4 string defining CRS, if default NULL, the value is read from the OGR data set"

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I also tried with OGRSpatialRef but it doesn't pick up the .prj file.

Comment: Hmm. Can't help you then. If there's not an error in the syntax you're using to call those functions, and if your shapefiles are correctly formed, this should work. Try, for example, `map <- readOGR(dsn = system.file("vectors", package="rgdal"), layer="scot_BNG"); proj4string(map)` or `OGRSpatialRef(dsn = system.file("vectors", package="rgdal"), layer="scot_BNG")` to see the expected behavior of those functions. The fact that it retains projection info is one big reason to prefer **rgdal** over **maptools** for data import.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use RShapePoly, try something like:

## to read the projection on your shapefile:

```
proj4string(yourshapefile.pr)
```

> [1] "+init=epsg:2163 +proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"
>
> ## now project it

```
yourshapefile.pr <- spTransform(yourshapefile, CRS( "+init=epsg:2163" )) #US National Atlas Equal Area
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to test this now, if someone is able to test it and it works I can mark the answer correct.